# How to compile a Java program using another program?

Tags: java, process, javac

all am working a project for compiling and running a java source code via my application.
here am stuck will explain my environment here..
`java 1.6.0_35 32bit` and `eclipse indigo` using  operating system `windows 64 bit`
when i used this code

```
String command = "javac "+file.getAbsolutePath();
System.out.println(command);
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);`
```

got this exception ..think error show file doesnt exist but i checked it,which is here
and when i execute via command line which compiles,but the eclipse shows this error

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "javac": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)`
```

can anyone fix this ,i tried a lot ..

Comment: It means the compiler `javac` is not in your path. I would try using the full path name to the javac.

Comment: u hum no way bro,i tried that already,i can compile the java source code through commandline :(

Comment: So when you tried the full path name it still fails?

Comment: can you please clarify the full pathnname stands for ??

Comment: is it  `
C:\Users\user>javac D:\Project\ServerCodeB\WebContent\Programs\Hello.java

C:\Users\user>
`

Comment: The directory where you can find `javac` followed by `javac` itself e.g. `String[] command = { "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\bin\javac", file.getAbsolutePath() };`

Comment: Its the javac it cannot find, not your file.

Comment: yeah path variable conatins C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_12\bin;

Comment: Which is a different version of Java. So what happened when you tried it?

Comment: when i tried to to compile through commandline i got the class file for the program

Comment: but when i tried in eclipse this error makes me stucks on this

Comment: ... and when you tried it in Java code using the full path name? Can you update the code and error in the question with the full path name?

Comment: File file2=new File("D:\\Project\\grow\\ServerCodeB\\WebContent\\Programs\\Hello.java");
  String command = "javac "+file2.getAbsolutePath();
  System.out.println(file2.exists());

Comment: output:true
javac D:\Project\grow\ServerCodeB\WebContent\Programs\Hello.java
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "javac": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)

Comment: So can you try *using the full path name of `javac`* in Java and give us the error message you get? Note: you need to use the `String[]` rather than the `String` as the program has a space in the full path name.

Comment: When something isn't doing what it should, its usually because you made some assumption which isn't right. ;) What you said should have worked, but given it didn't you have to consider what might be broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems not so much that the file you want to compile is not found, but that the javac command itself is not found. Make sure that the Runtime can find the javac executable, eventually by passing the "PATH=/path/to/java/dir" to exec.

See: [Runtime.exec(command, enviroment, dir)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String%5C%5B%5C%5D,%20java.io.File%29)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use the command line, you can access `javac` programmatically:

```
JavaCompiler javac = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
javac.run(null, null, null, arguments);
```

See

- [The Java 6.0 Compiler API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html#package_description)
- and http://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/guide/compilerAPI.html for examples

It is portable (works on other systems) and will avoid problems with paths and command line.

Comment: It is only portable as long as you are using Oracle's Java implementation - the class `com.sun.tools.javac.Main` is most likely not available in for example IBM's implementation. It's [not even guaranteed](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html) to work on future versions of Oracle's Java.

Comment: @Jesper: you are right, I meant more that it is usable on more systems (Windows, Linux, ...)

Comment: Edited with a more portable version (the user is using 1.6 so it should be OK)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Java 6 Compiler API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html#package_description) . Also [this link](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/73-the-java-60-compiler-api-1.html) might be useful..